# Get JSON from neo4j cypher query using spring-data-neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How can I convert the result Object returned from the template to Json? Is there any other simple way to get Json response using spring-data-neo4j?

```
Neo4jTemplate template = new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabase);
Object result = template.exec(new GraphCallback<Object>() {
            public Object doWithGraph(GraphDatabase graph) throws Exception {
                QueryEngine engine = graph.queryEngine();

                Result<Map<String, Object>> result
                    = engine.query("match n return n", null);

                for (Map<String, Object> m : result) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : m.entrySet()) {
                        Node node = (Node) e.getValue();
                        System.out.println("===>>" + node.getId());
                        System.out.println("===>>" + node.getLabels());

                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `template.query()` instead.

On the returned `Result<T>` you can use the `result.convert()` method with  your own `ResultConverter` to create JSON e.g. by using Jackson for Mapping